# Change label and colour for NA value in ggplot geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, na, geom-bar

I have a plot like this:

```
data <- data.frame(time = c("time1", "time2", "time1"),
                   sex = c("m", "f", NA))

ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = time, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..),
               fill = sex),
           position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "percentation",
                     labels = scales::percent)
```

and I am trying to change the label and colour of the NA value. I used `scale_fill_manual` like adding

```
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("m" = "male",
                               "f" = "female",
                               "NA" = "unknown"),
                    values = c("m" = "blue",
                               "f" = "red",
                               "NA" = "green"))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, so I would like to ask, if anyone here can help me with the problem? Is there a special word or something for selecting the NA values? Additional I would like to keep the direct assigning, like `"m" = "male"` and not just writing `"male"` to controll the assignment.

Comment: Which part doesn't work ? The color or the label ? If you check the `scal_fill_manual function`, you can see there is an argument called `na.value` for which you can give the color you want.

Comment: That's right, thanks. But I would like to change both, label and colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is working for me:

```
data <- data.frame(time = c("time1", "time2", "time1"),
                   sex = c("m", "f", NA))
data$sex = as.character(data$sex)

data$sex[is.na(data$sex)] <- "Unknown"


ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = time, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..),
               fill = sex),
           position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "percentation",
                     labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

I am not sure if you can directly do that. Thus convert `NA` to something first, then you can add your code:

```
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("m" = "male",
                               "f" = "female",
                               "Unknown" = "unknown"),
                    values = c("m" = "blue",
                               "f" = "red",
                               "Unknown" = "green"))
```

Comment: Thanks you, definitely this is a solution for my question. But I was wondering, if there is also a option, to change the label directly in the ggplot-call? Background is, that I have many variables and I would like to change the name in the plot not for every variable in my data.

Comment: Perhaps use `forcats::fct_explicit_na()`

Comment: Thank you! I am using your way now. I think for this (little) problem it is the easiest way.

Answer (score 6):

While the color for `NA` values can be esily adjusted with the `na.value =`  parameter of color/fill scales, the label in guides requires a little more work. However it can still be readily achieved *without modifying the data* using the very versatile function form of the `labels` parameter of the scale function:

```r
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(time = c("time1", "time2", "time1"), sex = c("m", "f", NA))

ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = time, y = after_stat(prop), fill = sex), position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_discrete(
    labels = function(breaks) {breaks[is.na(breaks)] <- "unknown"; breaks},
    na.value = "green"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 using the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: In one go: `labels = \(breaks) breaks |> modify_if(is.na, \(...) 'unknown')`